# can i search for all tagged photos associated with user some id i all of facebook users?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-actionscript-api

I'm using the the Adobe ActionScript 3 SDK for Facebook Platform to get all the tagged photos of the current user. Is this possible?

I've tried this:

```
FacebookDesktop.api("/"+uid+"/photos",getTagedPhotosHandler);
```

But that only gets me the photos belonging to that user.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to use FQL to perform the initial PID search...then batch the pids and request urls.  The following FB docs pages have further information:

[photo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/)

[photo_tag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/)

These requests would be necessairy:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=$uid
```

and

```
SELECT src, src_small, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid=$pid
```

you might be able to combine them into the following...

```
select src, src_small, src_big from photo where pid in (select pid from photo_tag where uid=me())
```

The final execution would look something like this:

```
Facebook.fqlQuery
(
    "select src, src_small, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid in (select pid FROM photo_tag where uid=me())",
    facebook_photosHandler
);
```

I believe extended permissions are required.  Each of the pages above should list permissions reqs for performing these FQL queries.

Best of luck.